# Struggling to install QGIS from source in RHEL 6.4

Tags: python, linux, rhel, qgis, rhel6

I have installed QGIS from source in Ubuntu using the [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) link. In ubuntu I compiled qgis from source without any problem.

but now I moved to RHEL 6.4, not able to run QGIS from source. The steps I have followed to install QGIS from source are described below.

First, I have added all repository which required by QGIS. They are as follows:

```
devtools-1.1.repo
elgis-testing.repo
elgis.repo
epel-testing.repo
epel.repo
remi-php70.repo
remi-safe.repo
remi.repo
rhel-source.repo
rpmforge.repo
slc6-extras.repo
slc6-os.repo
slc6-updates.repo
```

and I also installed Python 2.7, QScintilla2, GLIBC 2.14 from source because of version mismatching.

Then,I followed [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) link to build the QGIS, till this stage everything is fine. Build completed without any error.

After launching the QGIS application, It is showing an error saying that "Import Error:cannot import name Qgsfeature". this error is related to python versions, As I have two python versions installed my machine(Python 2.66 and Python 2.7). then I set the PYTHONPATH, But it is not affecting to the Application, So still displaying the same error.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/166454/115

Comment: I don't really know, but I've had some luck using the ci scripts as a base for my QGIS builds. You'll have to translate from debian: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/ci/travis/linux/before_install.sh, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/ci/travis/linux/install.sh, and then cd to the build directory and run `make`.